# Deleting a comment leaves gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm currently working on an idea whiteboard, but it seems that whenever I try to delete comments, blank spaces are left between the ideas.

For example, if I have the following comments:

[image]

But when I delete something:

[image]

How would I make it so that no gaps are left between comments?

Here is my code so far:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#chat').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    var socket = io.connect();
    var $messageForm = $('#sendmessage');
    var $messageTitle = $('#title');
    var $messageBox = $('#message');
    var $chat = $('#chat');

    $messageForm.click(function (e) {
        if ($.trim($("#title").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        }
        if ($.trim($("#message").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('You must provide valid input');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', '<span class="idea"><b>' + $messageTitle.val() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' + $messageBox.val() + '&nbsp;' + '[' + '<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>' + ']</span>');
            $messageTitle.val('');
            $messageBox.val('');
        }
    });

    socket.on('new message', function (data) {
        $chat.prepend(data + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

The HTML that remains:

```
<div id="chat"><span class="idea"><b>sfdf</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;czxczxc&nbsp;[<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>]</span>
    <br><span class="idea"><b>dsdfsd</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;sdfsdfsdf&nbsp;[<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>]</span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="idea"><b>dsfsdf</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;sdfsdf&nbsp;[<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>]</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<br>` on the end of the line (i.e. after each `<span>`), too?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/GYpdH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<br>`s to separate ideas, just add a CSS rule so that each idea is on its own line

```
<style>span.idea { display: block }</style>
```

and then

```
$chat.prepend(data + "<br/>");
```

becomes

```
$chat.prepend(data);
```

hopefully after you've filtered `data` to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use 'remove' instead of 'empty'.

Empty does not remove the element, it just empties it.

Manual:
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Tried it, it does the same thing.

Comment: That's strange. From the link:  "Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed."

Comment: Is there another structural element enclosing the comment that you actually reference to `.remove`? Can you post the HTML that remains after the remove?

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

i guess its the br that is still in the dom, that you insert by doing this:

```
$chat.prepend(data + "<br/>");
```

maybe you change you code so that it uses a list, that would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="id">message1</li>
    <li class="id">message2</li>
</ul>
```

you would have to edit change these lines:

```
socket.emit('send message', '<li class="idea"><b>' + $messageTitle.val() + '</b>' + '&nbsp;-&nbsp;' + $messageBox.val() + '&nbsp;' + '[' + '<a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>' + ']</li>');
```

some lines below change this:

```
$chat.prepend(data);
```

and on top add this:

```
var chatUlElement = $('ul');
var $chat = $('#chat').append(chatUlElement);
```